# Slack blocks with more than 2 columns

Tags: slack, slack-block-kit

I've a question regarding the blocks functionality in Slack.
Did anybody manage to build 3 instead of 2 columns?

I've intuitively tried the following code, which does not work:

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "header",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Description\t",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*Column 1*"
                },
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*Column 2*"
                },
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*Column 3*"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Previews can be generated here https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder

Answer (score 4):

I was dealing same issue and found a workaround using `\t` for tabulators

```json
{
    "type": "section",
    "fields": [
        {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*Column 1*\t\t*Column 2*\t\t*Column 3*"
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT: It looks terrible on phones